# iOS Personal Hotspot makes Navigation Controller Broken

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

When my personal hotspot is active, my Navigation Controller becomes broken like attached image. I tried full screen presentation on my NavigationController in storyboard; But it doesn't work.

[curropted one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzurB.jpg)

[correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zmJg.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Personal Hotspot breaks layout when navigation bar is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284901/ios-personal-hotspot-breaks-layout-when-navigation-bar-is-hidden)

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide blue bar Navigation. It's there to make sure you know that something is connected to the hotspot.

personal-hotspot is on , statusBar's height is 40

personal-hotspot is off , statusBar's height is 20